# Payum + Symfony2 - Add routing parameters to done-url

Tags: symfony, payum

using latest payum-bundle to create a captureToken i use this code:

```
$captureToken = $this->get('payum')->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken(
    $gatewayName, 
    $payment, 
    'done_xyz' 
);
```

but what if in my routing the 'done_xyz' requires a mandatory parameter? like

```
done_xyz:
    path:     /u/{parameter}/done_xyz
```

i get the error that its missing then, is there any way to include it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is forth argument of createCaptureToken that holds done url's parameters

This should work:

```
$captureToken = $this->get('payum')->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken(
    $gatewayName, 
    $payment, 
    'done_xyz', 
    ['parameter' => 'foo']
);
```

Comment: user3108662 pointed out that there is also a missing `'` (single quote) in the `foo` string. (@John)